# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
      <div class="head">
         @{Html.RenderAction("Top_Head", "My_PartialView");}
      </div>

      <div class="content">
                <div class="content-left">
                        <div class="ad">
                            <img src="~/Images/ImageFontEnd/ad.jpg" />

                        </div>

                    @RenderBody()


                 </div><!--END Content-left-->

              <div class="content-right">
                    <div class="##-lhe-support-login-sp" id="lien-he">
                     <div class="label-238px-box"></div>
                        <img src="~/Images/ImageFontEnd/call-pic.jpg" />
                    </div>
                 @{Html.RenderAction("Search_Price", "My_PartialView");}
```

2.created My_Partialview

```
using System;

namespace shopclothes.Controllers
{
    public class My_PartialviewController : Controller
    {
        shoponline1Entities db = new shoponline1Entities();
        // GET: /MyPartialView/

        #region[head]
         [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Top_Head()
        {

            return PartialView();
        }
        #endregion
     }
}
```

I follow the correct syntax? why it has been such a problem?

Comment: Probably you have unclosed tags in your HTML, please verify.

Answer (score 0):

The `@RenderBody` should be use on Layout views, try removing that

Answer (score 0):

error for:
  @{Html.RenderAction("Top_Head", "My_PartialView");}
 and 
 @{Html.RenderAction("Search_Price", "My_PartialView");}

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in using some @html.RenderAction or @html.Action together in layout .I recommend you try the equivalent of renderaction command in other ways.for more help you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353874/equivalent-of-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-core)