# Having error when displaying partial view in .NET Core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display Asset information on different pages using partial View but I am having the error below

> "InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'AssetInfo' could
> not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class,
> not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with
> 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the
> 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with
> 'NonViewComponentAttribute'."

Controller

```
  public ActionResult AssetInfo(int? Id)
  {
        var model = _context.Asset.Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();
        return PartialView("_AssetInfo", model);
  }
```

Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<InformationAssetRegister.Models.Asset>
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
    <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">
        Asset Name
    </th>
    <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">
       Asset type
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetType)
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

I tried to use Html.RenderAction but Renderaction cannot be use in .Net Core

```
  @{
    Html.RenderAction("AssetInfo", "Assets", new {Id= ViewBag.AssetId });
   }
```

I also tried the code below

```
   @await Component.InvokeAsync("AssetInfo", new { Id = ViewBag.AssetId })
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue I am new to .Net Core

Comment: Can you show the structure of the folder of your Views?

Comment: @Roar Being new to .net core did not know I need a ViewComponent call please can you help with that

Comment: I was trying to use Html.RenderAction but could not did some reach online but I think I am missing something but I don't know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `Html.RenderAction` has been removed in asp.net core. ASP.NET Core uses a new feature called ViewComponents to achieve the same thing. [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1). For more details about how to replace Renderaction with ViewComponents, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373265/7609093).

If you still want to use Html.RenderAction in asp.net core.

I suggest you could implement it by yourself, you could create a class and add below codes into your project.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
{

    public static class HtmlHelperViewExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent RenderAction(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, object parameters = null)
        {
            var controller = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            return RenderAction(helper, action, controller, parameters);
        }

        public static IHtmlContent RenderAction(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object parameters = null)
        {
            var area = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"];
            return RenderAction(helper, action, controller, area, parameters);
        }

        public static IHtmlContent RenderAction(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, string area, object parameters = null)
        {
            if (action == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(controller));
            if (controller == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

            var task = RenderActionAsync(helper, action, controller, area, parameters);
            return task.Result;
        }

        private static async Task<IHtmlContent> RenderActionAsync(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, string area, object parameters = null)
        {
            // fetching required services for invocation
            var currentHttpContext = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
            var httpContextFactory = GetServiceOrFail<IHttpContextFactory>(currentHttpContext);
            var actionInvokerFactory = GetServiceOrFail<IActionInvokerFactory>(currentHttpContext);
            var actionSelector = GetServiceOrFail<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>(currentHttpContext);

            // creating new action invocation context
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            var routeParams = new RouteValueDictionary(parameters ?? new { });
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area, controller, action });
            var newHttpContext = httpContextFactory.Create(currentHttpContext.Features);

            newHttpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();

            foreach (var router in helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Routers)
                routeData.PushState(router, null, null);

            routeData.PushState(null, routeValues, null);
            routeData.PushState(null, routeParams, null);

            var actionDescriptor = actionSelector.ActionDescriptors.Items.First(i => i.RouteValues["Controller"] == controller && i.RouteValues["Action"] == action);
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(newHttpContext, routeData, actionDescriptor);

            // invoke action and retrieve the response body
            var invoker = actionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(actionContext);
            string content = null;

            await invoker.InvokeAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    content = task.Exception.Message;
                }
                else if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    newHttpContext.Response.Body.Position = 0;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(newHttpContext.Response.Body))
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            });

            return new HtmlString(content);
        }

        private static TService GetServiceOrFail<TService>(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

            var service = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(TService));

            if (service == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not locate service: {nameof(TService)}");

            return (TService)service;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.RenderAction("AssetInfo", "Home", new { Id = 2 });
```

Home Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AssetInfo(int? Id)
    {
        //var model = _context.Asset.Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();
        var model = new List<Asset>() {
         new Asset(){ AssetName="te", AssetType="te2" }
        };

        return PartialView("_AssetInfo", model);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help I created a Html.RenderAction  as you suggested in your reply

Comment: Somehow the method is not working when the action method returns e.g. `Content("")`, any idea on this?