# Convert RenderAction partial view ASP.Net MVC to ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to convert this code from this asp.net mvc to asp.net core

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MyActionThatGeneratesAPartial(string parameter1)
{
    var model = repository.GetThingByParameter(parameter1);
    var partialViewModel = new PartialViewModel(model);
    return PartialView(_partialViewModel); 
}


@{ Html.RenderAction("MyActionThatGeneratesAPartial", "mycontrollerpartial"); }
```

because I'm more familiar with asp.net mvc, so I don't know what this code looks like in asp.net core

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353874/equivalent-of-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of Html.RenderAction in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353874/equivalent-of-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: ```Html.RenderAction``` has been removed in asp.net core. ASP.NET Core used new feature called ViewComponents to achieve same things. Article:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 way to work-around missing .NET CORE RenderAction functionality:

- Insert the partial and the method in a ViewComponent (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- Use javascript for doing the same thing:

> ```
> <div id="dynamicContentContainer"></div>
> <script>   
>     $.get('@Url.Action("MyActionThatGeneratesAPartial", "mycontrollerpartial")', {id : 1}, function(data){
>             $("#myActionContentContainer").html(data);
>         });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: There's also this post that explain how incapsulate in a ViewComponent: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2019/08/html-renderaction-equivalent-in-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

i share a sample code blow this.
public class aboutusViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
private readonly IService _services;

```
    public aboutusViewComponent(IService<AGWPservices> services)
    {
         _services=services;

    }

    public async Task< IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var services = _services.WhereByInclude(f => f.IsActive == true && f.IsDeleted == false && f.UseOnAbout == true,i=>i.Children).ToList()[0];

        return View("_aboutus",services);
    }

  
}
```

and use on html
@await Component.InvokeAsync("services")

it useful sample . and u can run with async