# ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

DataController

```
   public class FilterlistViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string text)
        {
            var result = text;
            return View(result);
        }

    }
```

Filter.cshtml

```
<div> 
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Filterlist", new { text = "test" })
</div>
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ7DE.png)

I applied the following solution exactly, but I am getting the following error.

[Equivalent of Html.RenderAction in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353874/equivalent-of-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-core/41373265#41373265)

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiCRW.png)

Comment: Hi @shopxada, where does your FilterlistViewComponent  locate?

Comment: Besides, for your view component `InvokeAsync` method, you return view with `result` and the `result` match the view name not the view model data. So when you pass `new { text = "test" }` to viewcomponent, you will return test view, that is to say you need change `Default.cshtml` to `test.cshtml` or just add a new view `test.cshtml` in your `Data/Components/Filterlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'Filterlist' could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.

Be sure **do not put** the ViewComponent class like below which locates **inside DataController**:

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Filter()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public class FilterlistViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string text)
        {
            var result = text;
            return View(result);
        }

    }
}
```

You need put it **outside the controller class** and it can be located in any other folder.

For example:

[image]

Besides, in  `InvokeAsync` method, you return view with `result` and the `result` match the **view name** not the view model data. So when you pass new `{ text = "test" }` to ViewComponent, you will return test view, that is to say you need change `Default.cshtml` to `test.cshtml` or just add a new view `test.cshtml` in your `Data/Components/Filterlist`.